# Dúvida wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Tenho uma dúvida bem básica. Estou começando a usar o *Wordpress* e gostaria de saber o que preciso fazer para configurar o tema *onepage*. Eu baixo o template mas quando o instalo ele está em formato de blog. Como usar o tema como pagina onepage como principal?

Comment: É necessário que o tema tenha suporte ao `onepage` para poder configurar, caso contrário você terá que adaptar o tema para uma versão `onepage`. Como você está aprendendo, você pode comprar/baixar um tema `onepage` em html e ir montando no WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
Pelo que eu entendi você já pegou um tema que tem como template a pagina estática. Na maioria dos temas que você baixa vem junto um manual/tutorial de como utilizá-lo e te aconselho muito a ler esse uma vez que a estrutura de sites diferem muito dependendo do tema que escolhe.

Mas para esse problema, se é o que estou pensando, você deve andar em **Configurações** > **Leitura** > selecionar "Uma pagina estática " e abaixo selecionar a pagina que você tem definida como *onepage*.